# What different between Android service's getApplicationContext() and Activity's getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I use getApplicationContext() to init a third part class,

```
new UPlusFinder(getApplicationContext())
```

The third pard class need some info in AndroidManifest file.

It return error when I call it in service And return OK when I call it in Activity, now I need init it in Service, How can I resolve this problem ?

Comment: Inside which method are you calling it?

Comment: What is error? add logcat

Comment: error log is Just start fail.

Comment: call it all in onCreate(),

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All！
No different between the two  `getApplicationContext()`, 
Just because Third part class need ask network， I call it in Activity in a Thread，and have't use Thread in Service,

now It works fine after I put it in a `thread`, but I don't know

How it recognize it's self run in a `thread`?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a few APIs,functions need current UI context.Both are provided by getApplicationContext().
getBaseContext() assuredly gives you the overall context.
Your third party application might need the current UI context which causes the error.
When you use a service,you are necessarily providing an application context which does not belong to the main thread and hence the failure to run certain methods